# Error while inserting child form into Parent form Angular2

Tags: angular, forms

I am following given [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/i04jLF)

to link my child forms with parent forms. I want to create canDeactivate guard to check whether user has done any changes in the forms or not? If any changes are there, user should get one confirmation dialog before navigating away.

In Child form, I am passing parent form with @Input tag, and in ngOnInIt block, adding child form into parent form.

While doing the same I am facing multiple issues.

```
this.childForm = this.fb.group({
input1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('.*[\\S].*')]],
});
this.parentForm.addControl('childForm', this.childForm);
// this.cd..markForCheck();
```

I have created canDeactivate guard in Parent component,

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  console.log(this.ParentForm);
    if (this.parentForm.dirty) {
      console.log('came to canDeactivate');
      return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Leaving this page will lose any changes made',
          header: 'Warning',
          icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
          accept: () => {
            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
          },
          reject: () => {
            observer.next(false);
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      });
    }
    console.log('came out of candeactivate');
    return true;
  }
```

1. No Provider for ChangeDetectorRef (while using it into child component)
2. I have create canDeactivate guard in parent component which check whether parent form is dirty or not. Over here, I have observed that in there are no child forms have been added into Parent Form.

Does anyone have faced this issue?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Guards should not be used in that way. Also @input should not be used to pass the form, it should be @ContentChild()

Comment: I think @Input is used to share the data from parent to child. Guard I have created to get the confirmation from the user that He is leaving the page but He has changed some values of the form.